# Cloud Anchor delegate methods not called

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality

Hey guys I am trying to retrieve and display a cloud anchor from my IOS app and never receive a delegate callback from resolve cloud anchor here is my view controller :

```
class ShowBooViewController: UIViewController,GARSessionDelegate, ARSessionDelegate  {


var garSession : GARSession? = nil
var arScene : SCNScene? = nil

@IBOutlet weak var arSceneView: ARSCNView!
@IBAction func showBoo(_ sender: UIButton) {


    let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Enter answer", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    ac.addTextField()

    let submitAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Submit", style: .default) { [unowned ac] _ in
        //let answer = ac.textFields![0]
        // do something interesting with "answer" here


    }

    ac.addAction(submitAction)
    present(ac, animated: true)
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    do {
        try self.garSession = GARSession.init(apiKey: "RedactedCuzSuperSecret",bundleIdentifier: nil)
        self.garSession?.delegate = self



        do {
            try self.garSession!.resolveCloudAnchor(withIdentifier: "bgfbgfbgf")
        } catch {
            print("Failed")
        }
    } catch {
        print("Failed")
        print(error)
    }
}


func session(_ session: GARSession, didResolve anchor: GARAnchor) {
    print("session")


}

func session(_ session: GARSession, didFailToResolve anchor: GARAnchor) {

    print("Session")
}

func session(_ session: GARSession, didHostAnchor anchor: GARAnchor) {
    print("Session")

}

func session(_ session: GARSession, didFailToHostAnchor anchor: GARAnchor) {
    print("Session")

}
```

}

The api key was changed to not post here but I have the actual api key in view controller, when using Xcode inspector I see that the delegate is assigned to the view controller I just do not get the session callbacks.

Comment: if `garSession`property is `nil` after you assign it with `try` block?

Comment: Gar session is not nil  :/ garSession GARSession? 0x000060000350d180
baseNSObject@0 NSObject 
_currentFramePair id 0x0 0x0000000000000000
_delegate _TtC3Boo21ShowBooViewController * 0x7f86e0e22b20 0x00007f86e0e22b20
_delegateQueue id 0x0 0x0000000000000000
_cloudAnchorManager GARCloudAnchorManager * 0x600003006c00 0x0000600003006c00
_hal GARLiveHAL * 0x600002c03ba0 0x0000600002c03ba0
_phenotypeManager GARPhenotypeManager * 0x600001e68180 0x0000600001e68180
_stateLock NSObject * 0x600001c11370 0x0000600001c11370
_delegateHelper GARSessionDelegateHelper * 0x600001c11380 ....

Comment: If there is an error, you can check onError delegation but there’s nothing with error maybe you must check network call or your info plist file